# Limit image width to Emacs window width?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I click on an image link, Emacs opens this image in a new window. Great! But some images are larger that the current window and Emacs doesn't provide scroll bars...

Is there a setting or function I can use, that will limit an image's maximum width to 100% of the current window?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this link help?: **Shrink/Zoom/Scale images in image-mode**:   http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2453/2287